# How to define integer variable in Play2 scala template

Tags: playframework-2.0

How to define integer or any variable in play2 scala template.

How to write below Java code in Scala template.

```java
int count=0;

if (count % 2)
  sysout "xyz"
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no straightforward way to do this, however you can use `defining`:

```
@defining(2) { count =>
  if (count % 2 == 0) xyz
}
```

The following will output xyz. There are limitations to this approach like you cannot reassign the value. So you cant do like this:

```
@defining(2) { count =>
  count = count*2
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a simple trick you can use. It is possible to define a variable in a template by putting a definition after an import. It must be in the same line but separated with a semicolon.

```
@import scala.Predef; val count = 0

@if(count % 2 == 0) {
    xyz
}
```